# All Intel drivers missing from Intel.com for older discontinued hardware?

Tags: drivers, bios, firmware

I have been trying to download various firmware's and drivers for older Intel Desktop Boards only to find that I could not find any of these drivers at Intel.com  like I used to do - It seems they removed every last driver of hardware that they discontinued.

I need some bios firmware updates for some of these boards and it seems I am now completely stuck, frustrated and even desperate. Maybe I'm missing something? Anybody have any ideas where I can find bios firmware's for older Intel Desktop boards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They did, yes. You can download the necessary drivers and updates from [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/downloadcenter.intel.com) (use the "View contents" link).

More information:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/intel/comments/dz0wfd/intel_is_removing_end_of_life_drivers_and_bios/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/d6dkoi/intel_removing_unknown_amount_of_drivers_and/f0v8sab/
- https://twitter.com/textfiles/status/1196880377526308865